# Making Users Prove They Have Reviewed The Information Security Policy Documents

Tags: corporate-policy

I am looking for a way to hold the departments accountable and ensure they atleast review the policies that we have.  I was thinking about using adobe sign **but don't want to go cloud**.  An application like those that make you scroll to the end then click agree would be nice if it kept track of the people who signed.  I'm looking for any recommendations, we have hundreds of users and docs.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here, and you are basically trying to solve a policy problem with tech solutions. A policy stating that the department *have to* review and specifying the punishment for not reviewing is what you need. They could send an email, or upload a file, or submit a form, or use wet ink on dead tree material... Anything that is behind authentication is enough for that.

Comment: Why do you want to track if they have read the documents? Why not simply get them to attest that they have read the documents? That's accountability. Scrolling to the end of a document does not mean they have reviewed them or make people accountable. You can't make people absorb information.

Answer (score 3):

Getting a web-page up with authentication and detection of "scroll to the bottom" should be fairly simple. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom

The problem is, that this does not guarantee that they even read the policy. See for example https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2757465, where quite a number where prepared to give up their firstborn child.

From time to time, we run small obligatory courses which highlight certain aspects of the policies. Sure, some seem to click through those courses relatively quickly, but they see the subject anyway. Being a big company, we also have the resources to embed small videos in these courses. But creating these courses is, of course, a lot of work.

You might create some quiz-type questions that must be answered. They might look-up the answer in the policy, which forces them to review at least that part. But unless you are enforcing a full exam on the policies which is required for the departments, you will find that there is always a possibility that the policy is 'just accepted'.

It must also be clear that violations of the policy might lead to consequences. And that the fact that you didn't know it was in the policies is never accepted as an excuse. "[Nul n' est censé ignorer la loi](https://translate.google.co.uk/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=Nul%20n%27%20est%20cens%C3%A9%20ignorer%20la%20loi)", as the French say.

By the way, I hope that the "hundreds" was for the users, not for the docs. If you have hundreds of docs that the users must read, you need to prioritize, and have a critical look at your policies. No user will read hundreds of policy docs, and even if they do, they won't remember them.